# Web speech api not working currently in chromium / electron / nw js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chromium, webspeech-api, google-speech-api

I have been creating a desktop application using electron, which uses the javascript web speech api. It was working perfectly until the last few weeks. Currently, it does not work. I tried using Nw js and I've also checked it in Chromium browser, where even the default Google's speech api demo site doesn't seem to work.

But it is working perfectly in Google chrome browser. Is google revoking chromium from using the API?

Is there any other option for me to use it in my desktop application. It is essential for my application to work using web technologies only, so I cannot query the actual programmatic API, I need to use the javascript api.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. It seems Google is moving more towards their Cloud Speech API: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/api-keys

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. It's sad Google suddenly revoked the access without notifying. It's currently working in Chrome app, I'm hoping they will continue providing speech recognition as free service in standard chrome environment.

Comment: Such a pity, it worked a few months ago.. I am working on a substitute based on Sphinx (an open-source speech recognition library) to bring back offline web speech recognition to Electron, I will post a real answer once it works

Comment: have you guys had any head way with this issue? Is google going to revoke the speechApi even in the browsers in the future for the api? And @Julian how is you offline lib coming along? Thank you guys in advanced

Comment: @TheMan68 I tried, but it's complicated: for this to work you need to prepare a dataset with the words you want to recognize. Google solved this with lot of money, time, and gigabytes of models stored on a cloud.

Comment: For reference, here is how they do it with Firefox. My guess is that it includes a dataset of common basic english words. Maybe that's what should be integrated in WebKit too, as it is open-source: https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/tree/86897859913403b68829dbf9a154f5a87c4b0638/dom/media/webspeech/recognition

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I guess ill just have to wait for the Qt implementation coming soon

Comment: Your comments were very helpful. Thanks