# React Native. MP3 Binary String (Uint8Array(9549)) to stream or file

Tags: javascript, react-native, amazon-polly, react-native-fetch-blob, uint8array

I am trying to play an audio file with binary string format that Amazon Polly returns. 
For that, I am using 'react-native-fetch-blob' and reading a stream, but just keep getting errors from the bridge saying 'Invalid data message - all must be length: 8'. 
It happens when I try to open the stream: `ifstream.open()`

This is the code:

```
//polly config
const params = {
    LexiconNames: [], 
    OutputFormat: "mp3", 
    SampleRate: "8000", 
    Text: "All Gaul is divided into three parts", 
    TextType: "text", 
    VoiceId: "Joanna"
};

Polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, function(err, data) {
    let _data = "";
    RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream(
        // file path
        data.AudioStream,
        // encoding, should be one of `base64`, `utf8`, `ascii`
        'ascii'
    )
    .then((ifstream) => {
        ifstream.open()
        ifstream.onData((chunk) => {
            _data += chunk
        })
        ifstream.onError((err) => {
            console.log('oops', err.toString())
        })
        ifstream.onEnd(() => {  
            //pasing _data to streaming player or normal audio player
            ReactNativeAudioStreaming.play(_data, {showIniOSMediaCenter: true, showInAndroidNotifications: true});
        })  
    })
});
```

Another solution I have also tried is to save the stream into a file to load it later on, but I got similars bugs.
`RNFetchBlob.fs.createFile("myfile.mp3", dataG.AudioStream, 'ascii');`

Huge thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `_data` defined? Can you include full path to audio file at Question?

Comment: Why do you request a `Blob` if you are expecting to read a stream of `Uint8Array`s in chunks?

Comment: @guest271314 thanks for helping on this.

Comment: No worries. Have no experience using `react-native`, `amazon-polly` or `react-native-fetch-blob`, though have tried `fetch()` and `ReadableStream` and various methods of trying text-to-speech at browser [How to use Web Speech API at chromium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013933/how-to-use-web-speech-api-at-chromium), [How to create or convert text to audio at chromium browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44346410/), [How to capture generated audio from window.speechSynthesis.speak() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45003548/)

Comment: I have just added all the missing code include the AWS Polly function. About requesting a `Blob`, I am not really sure, I would like just to be able to make `Uint8Array` a format compatible with the react player. Maybe push all the chunks into one array and save into a file. ideas?

Comment: You can use `Response.arrayBuffer()` at `fetch()` call then pass the array buffer to `new Uint8Array()`, though again, have no experience using react

Comment: Has anyone soved this yet?  I am using react-native-video and having the same problem.....

Answer (score 1):

You could use the getSynthesizeSpeechUrl method from [AWS.Polly.Presigner](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Polly/Presigner.html). I’m doing this and using react-native-sound to play the mp3. I ran into an issue where the mp3 wouldn’t play because my presigned URL contained special characters, but there’s a [fix here](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound/issues/223).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fetch()` to request one or more media resources, return `Response.body.getReader()` from `.then()` to get a `ReadableStream` of the response. Read the `Uint8Array` values returned as the stream as read with `.read()` method of the `ReadableStream`, append to value to `SourceBuffer` of `MediaSource` to stream the media at an `HTMLMediaElement`.

For example, to output the audio of two requested audio resources, in sequence

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {

  const audio = document.createElement("audio");

  audio.controls = "controls";

  document.body.appendChild(audio);

  audio.addEventListener("canplay", e => {
    audio.play();
  });

  const words = ["hello", "world"];

  const mediaSource = new MediaSource();

  const mimeCodec = "audio/mpeg";

  const mediaType = ".mp3";

  const url = "https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/";

  Promise.all(
      words.map(word =>
        fetch(`https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from data.uri where url="${url}${word}${mediaType}"&format=json&callback=`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(({
            query: {
              results: {
                url
              }
            }
          }) =>
          fetch(url).then(response => response.body.getReader())
          .then(readers => readers)
        )
      )
    )
    .then(readers => {

      audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
      mediaSource.addEventListener("sourceopen", sourceOpen);

      async function sourceOpen() {
        var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
        // set `sourceBuffer` `.mode` to `"sequence"`
        sourceBuffer.mode = "segments";

        const processStream = ({
          done,
          value
        }) => {
          if (done) {
            return;
          }
          // append chunk of stream to `sourceBuffer`
          sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(value);
        }
        // at `sourceBuffer` `updateend` call `reader.read()`,
        // to read next chunk of stream, append chunk to 
        // `sourceBuffer`
        for (let [index, reader] of Object.entries(readers)) {
          sourceBuffer.addEventListener("updateend", function() {
            reader.read().then(processStream);
          });

          let stream = await reader.read().then(processStream)
            .then(() => reader.closed)
            .then(() => "done reading stream " + index);

          console.log(stream);
        }

      }
    })
})
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/9zHwmcdG3UKYMghD0w3q?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately, this code will not work on React Native due the lack of `SourceBuffer` and support for `Uint8Array`

Comment: @user2956369 Why do you need to use React Native?

Comment: This is code is a mobile native app, that React Native compiles it into a JS bundle, it's not standard JS.