# speechSynthesis.getVoices() is empty array in Chromium Fedora

Tags: fedora, chromium

Is Speech Synthesis API supported by Chromium? Do I need to install voices? If so how can I do that? I'm using Fedora. Is voices like video that I need to install extra package for it to work?

I've tried this code:

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('I see dead people!');
msg.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices().filter(function(voice) {
    return voice.name == 'Whisper';
})[0];
speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
```

from article [Web apps that talk - Introduction to the Speech Synthesis API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk-Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API)

but the function speechSynthesis.getVoices() return empty array.

I've also tried:

```
window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function() {
    console.log(window.speechSynthesis.getVoices())
};
```

the function get executed but the array is also empty.

On https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Chromium there is info to use `--enable-speech-dispatcher` flag but when I've use it I've got warning that flag is not supported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is Speech Synthesis API supported by Chromium?

Yes, the [Web Speech API](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/speechapi.html) has basic support at Chromium browser, though there are several issues with both Chromium and Firefox implementation of the specification, see see [Blink>Speech](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=component:Blink%3ESpeech), [Internals>SpeechSynthesis](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list?q=component:Internals%3ESpeechSynthesis), [Web Speech](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=Web%20Speech).

> Do I need to install voices? If so how can I do that? I'm using
>   Fedora. Is voices like video that I need to install extra package for
>   it to work?

Yes, voices need to be installed. Chromium is not shipped with voices to set at `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` `voice` attribute by default, see [How to use Web Speech API at chromium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44013933/how-to-use-web-speech-api-at-chromium);  [How to capture generated audio from window.speechSynthesis.speak() call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003548/how-to-capture-generated-audio-from-window-speechsynthesis-speak-call).

You can install [`speech-dispatcher`](https://devel.freebsoft.org/doc/speechd/speech-dispatcher.html) as a server for the system speech synthesis server and [`espeak`](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) as the speech synthesizer.

```
$ yum install speech-dispatcher espeak
```

You can also set a configuration file for `speech-dispatcher` in the user home folder to set specific options for both `speech-dispatcher` and the output module that your use, for example `espeak`

```
$ spd-conf -u
```

Launching Chromium with `--enable-speech-dispatcher` flag automatically spawns a connection to `speech-dispatcher`, where you can set the `LogLevel` between `0` and `5` to review SSIP communication between Chromium code and `speech-dispatcher`.

`.getVoices()` returns results asynchronously and needs to be called twice

see this `electron` issue at GitHub [Speech Synthesis: No Voices #586](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/586).

```
window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = e => {
  const voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
  // do speech synthesis stuff
  console.log(voices);
}
window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
```

or composed as an asynchronous function which returns a `Promise` with value being array of voices

```
(async() => {

  const getVoices = (voiceName = "") => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      window.speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = e => {
        // optionally filter returned voice by `voiceName`
        // resolve(
        //  window.speechSynthesis.getVoices()
        //  .filter(({name}) => /^en.+whisper/.test(name))
        // );
        resolve(window.speechSynthesis.getVoices());
      }
      window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    })
  }

  const voices = await getVoices();
  console.log(voices);

})();
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the explanation. will test and mark your solution and upvote when it work, which probably will.

Comment: @jcubic See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/cancel

Comment: Installing speech-dispatcher and espeak was enough to make chromium speech work, as for `spd-conf -u` I've got error that command was not found and `--enable-speech-dispatcher` option show error about not supported flag when I launch chromium.

Comment: @jcubic `spdf-conf` should be included in `python3-speechd` package, though did find this Fedora bug report https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1408551. You can ignore the "You are using an unsupported command line flag" notification